# shifting the half columns of table to next page

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports

This is special requirement in which if there are 10 columns, let it be column1 to column10 of the same table.

Then in the first page of `report---contain` `Column1` to `column5`

and in second page of `report--contain` `column6` to `column10`.

Please help in this regard.

Report page `no1`

```
Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5
```

Report page `no2`

```
Column6 Column7 Column8 Column9 Column10
```

---

NB: -Here `column1` to `column10` belong to same table.

Answer (score 0):

Case 1: If there is only one row in the report:

1. Use two details sections (a & b).
2. Put columns 1 to 5 in details section a.
3. Put columns 6 to 10 in details section b.
4. Right click detail section b to use the "section expert" to check "new page before".

Case 2: If there are many rows in the report and you want to render each row in a pair of pages, do the same steps from 1 to 4 and add an extra one:

5. Right click detail section a to use the "section expert" to put a formula for "new page before". Use this formula:

   pagenumber > 1 //avoids a break page at the begining

Case 3: If there are many rows in the report and you want to show the first five columns of all rows in the first page and then show the last five columns of all rows in the folowing page:

1. Put columns 1 to 5 in details section. Don't create a second details section.
2. Create a subreport and put it in the report footer.
3. In the subreport, put columns 6 to 10 in details section.
4. In the main report, right click report footer to use the "section expert" to check "new page before".